# Tensor linearization question (C++ vectors)

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

**Problem**

Write a function:

```
vector<int> solution(vector<int> &P, vector<int> &Q);
```

that given a zero-indexed, tensor P which is linearized consisting of M integers and a zero-indexed array Q consisting of N integers representing the size of each dimension of the tensor. It returns an array of integers where each element of the output tensor is the mean of the corresponding element in the input, P, and its neighbors in each dimension. We can treat non-existent neighbors with zero value. Non existent neighbor means neighbor which are outside the tensor dimension. If we wish we can round up the values of the output arrays.

For example:

If P is [1,2,3,4,5,6] and Q is [1,2,3] the P represents the linearization of tensor with an inner-most dimension of 3 and an outer dimension size of 1.

Test case:

```
Input: [[44,14,92,6],[2,2,1,1]] 
Expected output: [17,7,16,12]
```

**Attempt**

I'm really struggling with the C++ implementation, but I "know" how to get the answer in my head, at least for the test case.

For example, for the test case:

```
Input: [[44,14,92,6],[2,2,1,1]] 
Expected output: [17,7,16,12]
```

We need to fill in the elements of the expanded array. Start in the first dimension and dig into the structure. In the index [0,0,0,0] we have value 44. Similarly, [0,1,0,0]->14. Then [1,0,0,0]->92, and [1,1,0,0]->6. Now we can calculate the means in the output.

The size of the 3rd and 4th dimensions is 1, so they have no neighbors and we use zeros. Thus the first element in the output is given by (44 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 14 + 0 + 92 + 0)/9 = 16.667, and rounding to the nearest integer gives 17. Similarly, for the second output, compute (14 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 44 + 0 + 6 + 0)/9 = 7.111, which rounds to 7.

To program this, the tricky part is definitely finding the neighbors of a given element from P. To do this, you need to convert the index in P to the corresponding list of indices of the expanded n-dimensional array. That way you can determine the neighbors by simping adding/subtracting 1 from each dimension. But I'm not very good with C++ vectors so I was having trouble.